# C# VSTO Merge Doc Level Ribbon and App Level Ribbon

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, ribbon

I have created a document level customisation in Excel that contains a ribbon and I would like to create an application level customisation for Excel which involves a ribbon of the same name. My problem is how do I get the two ribbon to combine? Currently, they have the same custom ControlId.

[image: Ribbon]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idQ property of controls exists to enable multiple add-ins to share containers, such as custom tabs and groups.

In the following VBA example, two Excel add-ins share the same "Contoso" group on the add-ins tab; each adds one button to it. The key is specifying the same unique namespace in the  tag. Then, controls can reference this namespace by using idQ.

> CustomUI for add-in 1

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" 
xmlns:x="myNameSpace" >
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab idMso="TabAddIns">
        <group idQ="x:Contoso" label="Contoso">
          <button id="C1" label="Contoso Button 1" size="large" 
            imageMso="FileSave" onAction="c_action1" />
        </group>
     </tab>
   </tabs>
 </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

> CustomUI for add-in 2

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" 
 xmlns:x="myNameSpace" >
   <ribbon>
     <tabs>
       <tab idMso="TabAddIns">
          <group idQ="x:Contoso" label="Contoso">
             <button id="C2" label="Contoso Button 2" size="large" 
               imageMso="FileSave" onAction="c_action2" />
          </group>
       </tab>
     </tabs>
   </ribbon>
 </customUI>
```

If you use a COM add-in to customize the Fluent UI, the namespace name must be the ProgID of the COM add-in, but the behavior is otherwise the same. When you use a shared add-in, the ProgID is AddInName.Connect. When you use Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Tools for the 2007 Microsoft Office System (Visual Studio 2005 Tools for Office Second Edition) to create the add-in, the ProgID is the name of the add-in.

You can read more about the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) in the following series of articles in MSDN:

1. [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
2. [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
3. [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: I am using visual design to design the ribbon interface. Is there an option for me to add custom namespace and change the ID to IDQ?

Comment: No, you need to use Ribbon XML to get the job done. You can right click on the designer and choose the export the ribbon markup. Then you can correct the XML markup adding the required namespaces.